# Android Emulator Ubuntu 14.04 Could not Create SDL2 Window GLX not Supported

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-emulator

A bit of background. I have a Centos 6 32 Bit server with Open VZ installed. I have created a VPS with Ubuntu 14.04.2 Desktop 32 Bit.

I am trying to install an Android emulator on the Ubuntu machine. I have followed a tutorial and I have eclipse and Android SDK installed on the server and everything functions correctly.

I have created an AVD and tried to start it. I originally had error messages relating to 32bit binaries which I have resolved, but now the progress bar gets so far and then I get the following error:

> emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
>
> ERROR; Could not create the SDL2 window: GLX is not supported

I can't help feel that this is the last error to fix before I finally get this guy to work. I have searched the error and there is not a great deal of information. I found a few articles that say to install the following:

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-swx11
```

I also found the following command but this gives me the same output:

```
emulator-arm -avd your_avd
```

Needless to say I have hit a bit of a brick wall, hence why I am here. Can any tell me how I could resolve the error?

A final bit of info, I am using Vnc to connect to the server.

Many thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Seeing the same thing when trying to run this via a Docker container

Comment: @Jochen Unfortunately not. I ended up using BluStacks on Windows. I asked the question in a few places and all of them went unnoticed. I Wish I had more for you, but every search I tried came up with little to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I found a quick answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338549/sdl2-cant-create-window-since-it-couldnt-find-matching-glx-visual)

```
export SDL_VIDEO_X11_VISUALID=0x022
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter the same problem.

I have use xmanager 4 as a x-server in my windows pc,
then I update to xmanager 5, and run emulator at ubuntu-host,
the "could not create sdl2 window glx is not supported" don't occur again,
but another error arises

> Could not create SDL2 window: Couldn't find matching GLX visual

I run `export SDL_VIDEO_X11_VISUALID=` at ubuntu-host before running the emulator, and it works.