# SDL2 Can't create window since it couldn't find matching GLX visual

Tags: c++, sdl-2, windows-subsystem-for-linux, glx

I have a problem as i am currently running Ubuntu Terminal on Windows 10. I also have XMing installed as my X-server(I use XMing for qemu,etc...). And i am trying to run this SDL2 Program. So i have this for main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

#include <SDL2/SDL.h> 
#include <GL/gl.h> 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
        int final_status = 1; 
        SDL_Window *window; 
        SDL_GLContext openGL_context; 

        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) { 
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to initialize SDL: %s\n", 
                        SDL_GetError()); 
                return 1; 
        } 
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("My Demo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
                                  SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, 
                                  SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL); 
        if (!window) { 
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError()); 
                goto finished; 
        } 

        openGL_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window); 
        if (!openGL_context) { 
                fprintf(stderr, "Can't create openGL context: %s\n", 
                        SDL_GetError()); 
                goto close_window; 
        } 

        /* drawing code removed */ 

        final_status = 0; 
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(openGL_context); 
close_window: 
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window); 
finished: 
        SDL_Quit(); 
        fprintf(stdout, "done\n"); 
        fflush(stdout); 
        return final_status; 
}
```

And then when i run `g++ main.cpp -lSDL2` , i get this output:

```
Can't create window: Couldn't find matching GLX visual
done
```

I have tried to search how to solve this GLX Problem but can't seem to find a solution for it. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have had this error once before, caused by not having a sufficient graphics driver or device available, as I was trying to run it through a badly configured virtual machine. Sorry that I can't be more specific.

Comment: @ygrichman hmm...   Well it is just an hello world app, and I think I got a good graphics card. And this is Wsl so it's on windows not virtual

Comment: I also have the error for a more advanced code, on a virtual machine. The code above doesn't give me the error though.

Comment: I also have the same error when trying to create OpenGL context with 32 bit depth buffer, looking with glxinfo and find out only 16 and 24 are supported

Answer (score 17):

Ensure that GLX is installed correctly by running `glxinfo`.  At the bottom, you'll find the list of supported visuals.  Here's mine:

```
1 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x022 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
```

Try running the following before running the SDL2 program:

```
export SDL_VIDEO_X11_VISUALID=
```

This causes SDL to go down a different code path to find the visual.  You can also try hardcoding the visual to the visual id from `glxinfo`:

```
export SDL_VIDEO_X11_VISUALID=0x022
```